# Next available number for multiple cases

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have an Excel worksheet with two columns: Column A and Column B.

Column A has all existing product codes.

Column B has all existing and new product categories. 
Product categories are two-digit numbers (with leading zeros, as required). 
(The product categories on existing products
are actually irrelevant to this question.)

Old product codes consists of two parts:
Two letters and six digits. The letters are always "ER" while the numbers were picked at random. So existing product codes are between ER000001 and ER999999.

New product codes will follow a new pattern

> "ER" + Product Category + a four-digit number

Both the product category and the four-digit number have leading zeroes,
as required. 
For example, if product category is 14, then all the new product codes in this category should between ER140001 and ER149999.

I need a formula that will create new product codes based on the product category in column B but not use any of the old codes above in column A.

Right now column A has 1100 products with their respective categories in column B and now we added another 500 rows with column B filled with categories but column A for those rows is still empty.

I am thinking about a formula using reference style.

```
If(RC2=R2C2:R[-1]C2,MID(R2C:R[-1]C,3,6))
```

To get array of products in category

Then use a formula with `row(indirect("$1:$9999"))` combined with `min(IF(IFNA(match(`

To check if a value is used... I am kinda lost.

The best case would be to have random numbers from
the available left, but sequential numbers would work fine as well.
No harm knowing how to do both, though.

```
         A        B
⑴    ER044747    05
⑵    ER044748    05
⑶    ER044749    05
⑷    ER044750    05
⑸    ER050009    05
⑹    ER069317    18
⑺    ER069318    18
⑻    ER420001    17
⑼    ER031134    17
⑽                17
⑾                17
⑿                05
⒀                22
⒁                22
⒂                42
```

The 05 product (Row 12) would take any value between
ER050001 and ER059999 except ER050009 since it was used before (in row 5).

The first 17 (Row 10) would take any value between ER170001 and ER179999. 
And the 2nd 17 (Row 11) would exclude the used value above it.

The 42 (Row 15) would take any value between
ER420002 and ER429999. 
ER420001 is unavailable since it was used in row 8.

So the result *could* be something like this:

```
         A        B
⑴    ER044747    05
⑵    ER044748    05
⑶    ER044749    05
⑷    ER044750    05
⑸    ER050009    05
⑹    ER069317    18
⑺    ER069318    18
⑻    ER420001    17
⑼    ER031134    17
⑽    ER170001    17
⑾    ER170002    17
⑿    ER050001    05
⒀    ER220001    22
⒁    ER220002    22
⒂    ER420002    42
```

where the bold italic values in cells A10:A15 are created by the formula.

Comment: The easiest thing may be to generate all possible values, then use a helper column with a `VLOOKUP`, `MATCH` or `COUNTIF` to see which ones already exist. Filter on the helper column and copy all new product codes.

Comment: Thank you for posting sample data ***as text** and not a screenshot.*  However, (1) It seems like unnecessarily much data.  You have posted 18 rows.  I believe that you could illustrate everything that you need to illustrate with 8 or 9 rows, and it would be easier to read.   (2) Your sample data seem to be incomplete.  I understand from your explanation that you have 1100 rows like the ones you show, but also 500 rows where Column A is blank.  You should show a few of those, too.   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Most importantly, you should show an example of the results that you want.  (4) Also, please *describe* what you want more clearly.  Do you want sequential numbers or random numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to cell `A1101`; i.e., the first blank cell in Column A. 
(This corresponds to `A10` in the sample data in the question.) 
Enter

```
="ER" & TEXT(B10,"00") & TEXT(MIN(IF(ISERROR(MATCH("ER"&TEXT(B10,"00")&TEXT(ROW($1:$9999),"0000"),A$1:A9,0)),ROW($1:$9999),10000)),"0000")
```

(replacing both occurrences of the number `10`
with the actual row number)
and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
If you’re already using R1C1 style, use

```
="ER" & TEXT(RC[1],"00") & TEXT(MIN(IF(ISERROR(MATCH("ER"&TEXT(RC[1],"00")&TEXT(ROW(R1:R9999),"0000"),R1C:R[-1]C,0)),ROW(R1:R9999),10000)),"0000")
```

(You don’t need to make any adjustments
because `RC[1]` means the next cell over in the current row,
without needing to use the actual row number.) 
Then drag/fill down to cover all the rows where Column B has a value.

This will generate (in each row)
the next available “ER” + Product Category + *nnnn* value;
i.e., the lowest possible value that hasn’t been used previously
(i.e., in Column A, above the current row).

[image: spreadsheet]

(The bold values in cells A10:A15 are generated by the formula;
the rest are constants.)

Comment: Note that there’s no need to say `ROW(INDIRECT("$1:$9999"))`; you can use `ROW($1:$9999)`.

Comment: Works perfectly! I can't thank you enough. The solution is so easy an elegant